# Populate Field With New DataEntry Form in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to use VBA to populate a field whenever a new record is being submitted.  I have dataentry set to yes so a new record appears each time the form is opened, but I can only get the username to populate with

```
Private Sub Form_Load().
    Me.Submitter = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
End Sub
```

The username appears right the very first time obviously, but after the last field, you hit TAB and a new record starts, but with no username.  Do I need to force the form to close and reopen after every new record?  Or is there something I'm missing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that was a short lived question.  By messing around I found that when you use `Dirty` instead of `Load` it works.

```
Private Sub Form_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.Submitter = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
    Debug.Print Me.Submitter
End Sub
```

I even put the `Debug.Print` in there to make sure it wasn't constantly looking to repopulate that field with each keystroke or changing of fields, and it does not.  As soon as I open the form and start entering data, that first keystroke populates my username and it's done until the next record.